# Issue with plugging monitor on my laptop

Tags: 14.10, monitor, dvi

I have a dell monitor (DELL E1913) plugged on my laptop (Dell XPS 13 developer edition, ubuntu 14.10). I have a mini display port - DVI adapter connected on my laptop, this adapter is plugged on the DVI cable of the monitor.

In the configuration panel of Ubuntu, the Dell monitor is well detected, I can see it, but the monitor says "No Signal".

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Common solutions are:

- Try pressing Fn+F1 until you get the setting you want (on your particular model, for example on my MSI laptop it is Fn+F2)
- Go to Display using for example the Dash and look if your second screen is present, click on it and try to switch it on with the switch on the left side.

Comment: Fn+F1 doesn't switch to my external monitor. I have moved the second screen at the left of the first screen but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to see if DVI output is supported by my laptop?

Comment: precision : the monitor detects well the dvi cable from the laptop. But when i plug the cable, the monitor says : entering power save mode

Comment: Try to switch off or change the power-saving / sleep mode setting of your monitor. Otherwise it could be anything.

Comment: I believe that as long as the monitor won't get any signal from the pc, I won't be able to access the menu that allow to change power-saving settings...:/ For now I can only see input selection menu.